# NSIndexPath does not have a member named row in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    var myArr = [(id:1, name:"1123", description:"d1", image:"palm-tree.png"), (id:2, name:"23", description:"d2", image:"palm-tree.png"),
                (id:3, name:"3", description:"d3", image:"palm-tree.png"), (id:4, name:"4", description:"d4", image:"palm-tree.png")]

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            var indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
            let destinationViewController:DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
            destinationViewController.myArr = myArr[indexPath.row]
        }
    }

}
```

And I have an error **NSIndexPath does not have a member named row**. How to fix that?

Thanks!

**Update:**

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    struct Item {
        let id: Int
        let name: String
        let description: String
        let image: String
    }

    var myArr = [Item(id:1, name:"1123", description:"d1", image:"palm-tree.png"),
        Item(id:2, name:"23", description:"d2", image:"palm-tree.png"),
        Item(id:3, name:"3", description:"d3", image:"palm-tree.png"),
        Item(id:4, name:"4", description:"d4", image:"palm-tree.png")]
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
                let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
                destinationViewController.myArr = [myArr[indexPath.row]]
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And **DetailViewController**:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    struct Item {
        let id: Int
        let name: String
        let description: String
        let image: String
    }
    var myArr = [Item(id:1, name:"1123", description:"d1", image:"palm-tree.png")]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()` returns an Optional `NSIndexPath` -- you need to unwrap it to access the `row` property:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
            destinationViewController.myArr = [myArr[indexPath.row]]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **'Int' is not convertible to 'Range<Int>'**

Comment: Looks like your `DetailViewController` is expecting an Array - I've updated the answer so it will get a one-element array with the current row's data from `myArr`. (BTW, those are not good variable names. Be descriptive!)

Comment: Sorry, its my mistake - I forgot about 'DetailViewController':  var myArr: (id:Int, name:String, description:String, img: String) = (id:0, name:"", description:"", img:"")

Comment: and I have error **'(id: Int, name: String, description: String, img: String)' does not have a member named 'Element'**

Comment: Using a tuple to pass data like this between view controllers is going to bring you lots of problems. Define a `struct` with these four members, and use that to create your `myArr` and as the data type for your detail view controller. My guess is that the error messages you're seeing will either go away or be more informative, and you'll get proper type-checking.

Comment: I have updated the post, now I have an error: 'ViewController.Item' is not convertible to 'DetailViewController.Item'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62622/discussion-between-nate-cook-and-tim).