# Xcode 6.3.2 Swift 1.2 NSIndexpath does not have member 'row'

Tags: ios, swift, nsindexpath

I have a class I use to encapsulate data handling - similar to NSFetchedResultsController, but custom to the needs of the app. I'm converting this class to Swift (dual attempts are for illustration, not actual implementation).

```
@objc class DataHandler: NSObject {

    final func deleteEntryAt(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let entry = entries[indexPath.row]

        let iRow = indexPath.row
        if let row = indexPath.row {

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

And the Objective-C version, which functions as expected:

```
- (void)deleteEntryAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    Entry *entry = self.entries[indexPath.row];

}
```

Looking at the NSIndexPath header and documentation, for both Swift and Objective-C reveals no property or function named 'row'; so, I'm at a loss.

Note: I have tried both optional and non-optional variations.

The passed NSIndexPath in the sample code is non-optional, which is why I believe this issue is different than the following:

- [NSIndexPath? does not have a member name 'row' error in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040405/nsindexpath-does-not-have-a-member-name-row-error-in-swift)
- [NSIndexPath does not have a member named row in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26241567/nsindexpath-does-not-have-a-member-named-row-in-swift)

Nor does the method have any outside knowledge at this point for the issue to be similar to this:

- [Swift ViewController does not have member named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28935558/swift-viewcontroller-does-not-have-member-named)

At least I don't think so. If this is a duplicate of those, such is life and I do apologize.

**Update:**

Clean & build - no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `UIKit`.

`section`, `row` and `item` are properties of `NSIndexPath` added by UIKit.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/index.html